# gcc compile time type resolution

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I have three files, say A.c , B.c and C.c, all of which #include common.h

In common.h, I include "sys/socket.h" and I protect the common.h by macros:

```
#ifndef __COMMON_H
#define __COMMON_H
// body of file goes here
#endif
```

When i compile the code, I get several errors such as below

```
In file included from /usr/include/sys/socket.h:40,
             from tcpperf.h:4,
             from wrapunix.c:1:
/usr/include/bits/socket.h:425: error: conflicting types for 'recvmmsg'
/usr/include/bits/socket.h:425: note: previous declaration of 'recvmmsg' was here
In file included from /usr/include/sys/socket.h:40,
             from tcpperf.h:4,
             from wrapsock.c:1:
```

As you can see wrapunix.c and wrapsock.c, they both include tcpperf.h, but tcpperf.h is guarded with macros,yet gcc complains that recvmsg was declared multiple times. How do I resolve this issue?

Update:
Here is the header of tcpperf.h, that is causing issues

```
#ifndef _TCPPERF_H
#define _TCPPERF_H
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <argp.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <linux/tcp.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#endif
```

The above error can be reproduced by providing "-combine -fwhole-program" flags to gcc such as

gcc -std=gnu99 -Wall -combine -fwhole-program -I. error.c wrapunix.c wrapsock.c file1.c file2.c -o file2 -lrt

Comment: Check for circular dependencies; Two headers including each other might cause this, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Identifiers with two leading underscores or with one leading underscore and a capital letter are reserved for use by the language implementation.

Comment: @esa there are no circular dependencies. Wrapunix.c includes only one file called tcpperf.h. wrapsock.c also includes only one file called tcpperf.h

Comment: I can't reproduce this (and my `/usr/include/bits/socket.h` is only 410 lines long and contains no `recvmmsg`). Can you post your `/usr/include/bits/socket.h` somewhere?

Comment: @Jimm What is the output of `gcc -Wall -c tcpperf.h` ?

Comment: @melpomene i can reproduce it ONLY with following flags to gcc -combine -fwhole-program

Comment: @Jimm `gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-combine’`

Comment: @melpomene what version of gcc do you use? I use gcc version 4.4.6 20120305.

Comment: @Jimm is it necessary that you `-combine` your source files? Have you tried cleaning all pre-existing objects and re-running GCC? Edit: I can also confirm that GCC 4.7.2 does not provide `-combine`, either.

Comment: @EsaLakaniemi yes i cleaned all preexisting object. And no it is not necessary. Would you know why -combine would cause this error?

Comment: @Jimm It sounds like the command line option is combining some form of your source files into one big mess: It might be due to a bug or something but I'd *presume* that what's happening is that the compiler is processing the `#include` statements in a way that causes the header to appear several times within the composed source file. Combined with future versions of GCC not including the `-combine` option, you might wish to refrain from using it, unless necessary.

Comment: `-combine` is deprecated in gcc 4.5 and later.  Use `-flto` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The error is "conflicting types for 'recvmmsg'" rather than just duplicate definition (which would be tolerated if equal). That means your .c source receives two different version of recvmmsg: one by your direct tcpperf.h inclusion and another one by inclusion it via sys/socket.h. I believe you have another version of tcpperf.h elsewhere in inclusion path with different (perhaps older version) recvmmsg.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is almost certainly related to `-combine`.  This is a bit of a guess, but in looking at the definition of `recvmmsg`:

```
extern int recvmmsg (int __fd, struct mmsghdr *__vmessages,
                     unsigned int __vlen, int __flags,
                     __const struct timespec *__tmo);
```

note that it takes a `struct mmsghdr` as an argument.  However, while this prototype is unconditional, `struct mmsghdr` is only defined if `__USE_GNU` is set:

```
#ifdef __USE_GNU
/* For `recvmmsg'.  */
struct mmsghdr
  {
    struct msghdr msg_hdr;      /* Actual message header.  */
    unsigned int msg_len;       /* Number of received bytes for the entry.  */
  };
#endif
```

`-combine` is basically equivalent to concatenating all your files together and then compiling them.  Is there any chance that between the text of `wrapunix.c` and `wrapsock.c` that `GNU_SOURCE` is being defined?  If that happened, then the first definition of `recvmmsg` would use a definition of `struct mmsghdr` that was local to just the prototype, while the second definition would use the real struct.  Those two definitions would then be incompatible, which would result in the error message that you got.